# Show that a subspace is closed in a Hilbert space $H$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $T$ is a bounded linear operator in a Hilbert space $H$, and $T$ is self-adjoint and is equal to its inverse, how can I show that $\widehat{H} = \{h + Th : h \in H\}$ is closed? If I consider the sequence $\{\widetilde{h_n} \}$ with $\widetilde{h_n} \equiv h_n+Th_n$ that converges to the limit $x$, can I use the uniqueness of representation of the limit to show that $x\equiv h+Th$, to show that $\widehat{H}$ is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose a sequence $(h_n+Th_n)$ in $\hat{H}$ converges to some $x$, i.e., $h_n+Th_n\to x$. Applying $T$ and using the fact that $T^2=id$, we obtain
$$Tx=\lim T(h_n+Th_n)=\lim Th_n+h_n=x,$$
so $x=\frac{x+Tx}{2}=\frac{x}{2}+T\frac{x}{2}\in\hat{H}$, which shows that $\hat{H}$ is closed.